# Tensorflow Seq2Seq error with different length inputs and outputs

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I have been working on a seq2seq model based off of [this](https://github.com/hans/ipython-notebooks/blob/master/tf/TF%20tutorial.ipynb) tutorial (with a few changes in an attempt to make it work with different length inputs and outputs), just using my own dataset with padded symbols. But whenever I try to have different length inputs and outputs, I always get the following error whenever I try to get a prediction out of it:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'labels0' with dtype int32
 [[Node: labels0 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_INT32, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

For the record, here are the important parts in my code where I define the variables and that stuff

Vairables:

```
encInput = [tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = (None,), name="inp%i" % t) for t in range(seqLengthT)]

labels = [tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = (None,), name="labels%i" % t) for t in range(seqLengthH)]

weights = [tf.ones_like(labels_t, dtype = tf.float32) for labels_t in labels]

decInput = ([tf.zeros_like(encInput[0], dtype = np.int32, name = "GO")] + labels[:-1])

prevMem = tf.zeros(batchSize, memoryDim)
```

Seq2Seq model:

```
decOut, decMem = seq2seq.embedding_rnn_seq2seq(encInput, decInput, cell, vocabSizeT, vocabSizeH, embeddingDim, feed_previous = False)
```

Loss:

```
loss = seq2seq.sequence_loss(decOut, labels, weights, vocabSizeT)
```

Inputs for testing:

```
feed_dic = {encInput[t]: batchX[t] for t in range(seqLengthT)}  feed_dic[keep_prob] = 1
```

Here is the line that seems to cause all the problems:

```
decOutBat = sess.run(decOut, feed_dic)
```

What makes no sense to me is that I have tried everything I can think of, and I get nowhere with it. I have made sure that I am feeding in an array in the correct dtype, I have made sure that all the variables are the correct length they should be. What is interesting is that it works fine for the first input, which is the "GO" symbol, but then after that it doesn't work. And when I run it with equal sequence lengths for both input and outputs it works fine, runs normally. I just want it to run this way because when I output prediction, it says thinks they are all 0s, which is the pad sequence, and I don't fully understand how to implement bucketing, so this is the best route for me to go.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: Here is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tucker/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 972, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/tucker/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 954, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/home/tucker/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/home/tucker/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors.py", line 463, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'labels2' with dtype int32
     [[Node: labels2 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_INT32, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 57, in <module>
    bTest(testX, testY, batchSize)
  File "network.pyx", line 383, in network.bTest (network.c:8672)
    output = test(eX)
  File "network.pyx", line 243, in network.test (network.c:6589)
    decOutBat = sess.run(decOut, feed_dic)
  File "/home/tucker/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 717, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/tucker/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 915, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/tucker/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/tucker/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 985, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'labels2' with dtype int32
     [[Node: labels2 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_INT32, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'labels2', defined at:
  File "run.py", line 30, in <module>
    encInput, labels, weights, decInput, prevMem = createVariables(seqLengthT, seqLengthH, batchSize, vocabSizeT, vocabSizeH, embeddingDim, memoryDim)
  File "/home/tucker/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1332, in placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/home/tucker/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1748, in _placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/home/tucker/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 749, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/tucker/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2380, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/tucker/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1298, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'labels2' with dtype int32
     [[Node: labels2 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_INT32, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Comment: The error you see should have nothing to do with input / output sizes. Can you post a longer stack trace?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos added it

Comment: So it looks like somehow your prediction subgraph depends on the labels (this is why you see the placeholder error message). Can you visualize your graph on tensorboard and see why that's the case?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos how would I go about doing that?

Comment: The tensorboard documentation on visualizing graphs is a good place to start looking: https://www.google.com/search?q=tensorboard+graph&oq=tensorboard+graph&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.3601j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8